# Is it possible to get different results if I use strictfp using docker installed on different OS?

Tags: java, docker, ieee-754, platform, strictfp

I use some double math operations without `strictfp` in my code.

I run docker on different OS but everywhere I use the same dockerFile.

Is it posssible to get different results in my math operations?

P.S.

I know that Strictfp ensures that you get exactly the same results from your floating point calculations on every platform. But I am not fully sure what does it mean 'platform'

Comment: have you tried on different OS e.g linux and windows so you can compare the results ?

Comment: I have only one OS now but I curious to know what happens on another OS

Comment: Java is a JIT-compile language, so the final machine code is generated on each target platform. Easy to imaging that you'd get different results on platforms with/without FMA if the (JIT) compiler is allowed to contract `x*y+z` into `fma(z, x,y)`. e.g. x86 Sandybridge vs. Haswell, or in a VM that doesn't expose AVX/FMA. If you had a docker image with ahead-of-time compiled binaries that don't do any runtime dispatching based on instruction availability, *that* would be deterministic. Especially if we rule out 32-bit x86 where instructions like `fsin` might not give identical results everywhere